# Lightroom + bridge workflow

Tags: lightroom, adobe-bridge

I tend to keep all my photos in lightroom, which is usually my starting point. So, I also keep there the photos I have edited in photoshop FROM lightroom.

On occasion though, I start working directly in photoshop (say, creating a composition which blends images from the internet, parts of my photo(s) etc.

At that point I'm never sure whether I should import the final image into LR, or save it somewhere else and use Bridge to categorise/manage/etc.

Do you have any suggestions? how do you use LR and Bridge together?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't catalog just with LR. LR allows you to import from a variety of locations...you do not necessarily need to import from just a memory card. It has collections and smart collections as well, and there is no reason you couldn't use those to catalog your photomanip parts, pieces, and source material alongside the manips themselves, and all the rest of your work. This may just be me, but when I have a library, I like there to be just one, for it to be central, and for it to be comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

I always just use LR and let it keep track.  Stacks work nicely if it is primarily based on one image, though if you have combined multiple, perhaps either using keywords or putting it in some collection of edited works would fit well.